# Find custom type in Object

Tags: c#, object, types, recursion, propertyinfo

I have a Upload class with different properties and I like to find each UploadObject property in this class or inside of other propertys. How can i find all UploadObjects in my Upload class?

```
class UploadObject
{
    public string ID {get; set;}
    //...
}

class PicUpload
{
    UploadObject Pic {get; set;}
    //...
}

class FileUpload
{
    UploadObject File {get; set;}
    //...
}

class Upload
{
    //..
    FileUpload File {get; set;}
    List<PicUpload> Pics  {get; set;}
    //...
    UploadObject Something {get; set}
}
```

Edit:
I'm searching for a function like:

```
public object[] FindProperties(object objectTree, Type targetType) {}
```

Comment: You're startpoint is an instance of class Upload?

Comment: What would the array returned from your `FindProperties` function contain?

Comment: @PHeinberg All UploadObjects that the function had found.

Answer (score 2):

```
typeof(Upload).GetProperties()
   .Where(p => typeof(UploadObject).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType));
```

will return all properties where the return type is UploadClass or inheriting class. Then you would have use recursion on it with a stop condition on types that can't possibly contain an UploadObject. The stop condition could be to check if the return type is a primitive type using `IsPrimitive` (available on `Type`).

You can replace the IsAssignableFrom with `== typeof(UploadObject)` if you just want that specific type.

**Edit:**

This is the idea I had in mind. Disclaimer: The only testing I have done is to compile it and run it against one scenario, for which it worked, but it illustrates the idea.

```
public static T[] GetAllPropertyValuesForTypeinTree<T>(object rootObject)
{
    var propertyInfos = rootObject.GetType().GetProperties();
    var withCorrectPropertyType = propertyInfos
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(T)).ToList();

    var withListsOfType = propertyInfos.Where(p => 
        IsEnumerableOf<T>(p.PropertyType)).ToList();
    var complexProperties = propertyInfos.Except(
         withCorrectPropertyType.Concat(withListsOfType))
         .Where(p => !p.PropertyType.IsPrimitive && !p.PropertyType.IsGenericType);

    var complexValues = new List<T>();
    foreach (var complexProperty in complexProperties)
    {
         complexValues.AddRange(GetAllPropertyValuesForTypeinTree<T>(
             complexProperty.GetValue(rootObject, null)));
    }

    var listValues = withListsOfType.Select(p => 
        (IEnumerable)p.GetValue(rootObject, null))
        .SelectMany(p => p.OfType<T>());
    var propertyValues = withCorrectPropertyType.Select(p => 
        (T) p.GetValue(rootObject, null));
    return propertyValues.Concat(listValues).Concat(complexValues).ToArray();
}

private static bool IsEnumerableOf<T>(Type type)
{
    if (!typeof (IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type)) 
        return false;

    return type.GetInterfaces().Any(interfaceType => interfaceType.IsGenericType
        && (interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>) 
        && type.GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(T)))
        || type == typeof(IEnumerable<T>);
 }
```

You would call it with:

```
var propVals = GetAllPropertyValuesForTypeinTree<UploadObject>(theInstance);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
typeof(UploadClass).GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(UploadObject));
```

Comment: @Florlan07 Would it not be better to use `Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(UploadObject));`